# Flexbox (old) bound two elements to each side

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there any possibility to recreate the `justify-content: space-between` for the browsers who use the old Flexbox spec (in my case mobile browsers)?
I needed to align two elements: One to the left and the second to the right side but without any floats but preferable with Flexbox.

With the new flexbox it's easily possible:

```
<div class="two-columns">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { 
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
    justify-content: space-between;
}

div span { 
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R8bbz/1/

Comment: What browsers and versions are you targeting?

Comment: You might find this helpful for comparing properties/values between the different drafts:  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Poor Man's Flexbox Knock-off

You could mimic the flexbox effect by using absolute positioning.

Add two classes to you `span` elements:

```
<div class="two-columns">
    <span class="left">1</span>
    <span class="right">2</span>
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```css
div { 
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
}

div span { 
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 30px;
}  
div .left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
}
div .right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; 
    top: 0;
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/JxYwg/

You may want to put a minimum width to the parent container to keep the boxes from
overlapping if you get extremely small screen sizes.

The flexbox spec is still pretty new and not that widely supported:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

If you altered your mark-up, you could use CSS table-cell to get a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

The old 2009 equivalent is `box-pack: justify`.  For the March 2012 draft (which IE10 uses), the equivalent is `flex-pack: justify`.